# Firebase SDK (v2.5.0) in OSX framework

Tags: swift, macos, frameworks, firebase

I'm trying to link to the Firebase SDK (v2.5.0) within my OS X framework, but it keeps telling me I am trying to link to a framework built for iOS.

It seems to state pretty clearly on the Firebase docs that the iOS framework can be used to build OS X clients as well, so does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

```
ld: in /[...]/Firebase.framework/Firebase(Firebase.o), building for OSX, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2.4.0 ([changelog](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/changelog.html)), Firebase no longer ships a single binary for iOS and OSX, but instead has multiple frameworks (Firebase.framework for iOS, FirebaseOSX.framework for OSX). Similarly, the iOS Cocoapod is named [Firebase](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase), while the OSX Cocoapod is named [FirebaseOSX](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseOSX). This is due to several changes in our build process, such as adding bitcode support (which only makes sense on iOS).

We still build and release iOS and OSX through these channels, and continue to support OSX, though it's not heavily advertised (as you noticed). As mentioned, if you don't use Cocoapods, using https://cdn.firebase.com/ObjC/FirebasePlatform.framework-major.minor.patch.zip will get you the framework, then follow the [Alternative Setup instructions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/alternate-setup.html) for including it in your project.

Comment: Thanks for verifying this! I think though that it would be worth a small link or something, as it is very easy to misunderstand the documentation now, which essentially says the SDK can be used for OSX as well, when in fact it can't, and there is only a link to the iOS SDK. :)

Comment: My firebase crashes in the authUser block with: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Why are the arguments defined as non nil? 2.5.1

Comment: Can you start a new question on SO and post the code so we can see what's what you're doing?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Sorry but do you know how to create a mac application on Firebase? I only see iOS, android and webapp options. Which one should I use

Comment: @sahara108 as of the 3.x clients, we don't have macOS support. I recommend using the 2.x clients, per this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/gber4k8nmsI/kvOKRCVuAwAJ;context-place=forum/firebase-talk

Comment: Does firebaseOSX provide the push notification feature also like firebase for IOS ?

Comment: @taha027 nope, just the realtime database (and the old version at that).

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Thanks !

Comment: @MikeMcDonald. please answer to this question also.It will be quite helpfull.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407473/firebase-notification-integration-on-cocoa-os-x-application

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some dependencies in your project's `Build Phases`:

> libicucore.dylib
>
> libc++.dylib
>
> CFNetwork.framework
>
> Security.framework
>
> SystemConfiguration.framework

See the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html) on how to add these if you haven't done this before.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't help, I am not totally sure that is the problem I am having as it explicitly complains about the framework being build for iOS?

Comment: I'm doing it manually, I'd like to avoid using CocoaPods in this case.

Comment: And have you added a bridging header to your project and imported the framework?

Comment: Bridging headers aren't supported in framework targets, so no I haven't. When writing code though, it all works, auto completion etc, it's just the linking that fails, so I can't actually build anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a bit weird.. But after digging around in the pod specs I noticed that the FirebaseOSX podspec links to a different url than the iOS pod (FirebaseOSX.framework and an older version).

So I decided to copy the framework url from the Firebase site, and change the name and try that, and it downloaded a OSX framework for me. This is really weird, because I can't for the life of me understand that I should do like that based on what I can read on the Firebase site, so I can't really consider this the official way as it doesn't really make any sense. But it seems to work for now..

So for v2.5.0 the url is:

```
https://cdn.firebase.com/ObjC/FirebaseOSX.framework-2.5.0.zip
```