# Firebase Notification Integration on cocoa os x application

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, firebase

I am currently doing a R & d to add firebase  to mac os x application. I found a pod `'FirebaseOSX'` and install it, but i can't find how to integrate push notifications feature through firebase like IOS and android in cocoa application.
Does anyone do that ? Please help!

Thanks,

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is currently iOS only. The `FirebaseOSX` pod is a legacy pod containing only the Realtime Database, created before the expansion of Firebase at Google I/O 2016.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Will there be any chances that firebase provide the support on os x in future ?

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/gber4k8nmsI/ehd45IHeFQAJ

Answer (score 0):

There is now community supported Firebase support for macOS available on [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk#macos).